Restore default behavior in Angular after onPopState override
I'm wondering if is possible to restore dafault behavior after overriding location.onPopState?
My code looks like this:
this.location.onPopState(() => {
    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    closeOverlay();
});

Main purpose is to close fullscreen overlay and I want to place in closeOverlay() function logic to restore default and be able to navigate again with it.
Is this possible?
Thanks
